# Cound someone help to check if this paper is talking about sound absorption coefficient of the air?

Tags: acoustics, dissipation, absorption

I am trying to [compute the distance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/527013/252362) I stand away from a sound source and still can detect the sound although I cannot hear clearly what the speaker is saying.

Given the threshold of human hearing and one watt sound source are known quantities, only one quantity is the absorption coefficient of the air. So I googled it and got this [paper](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/252003.pdf), which seems not to be relevant.

cound someone help to check if that paper is talking about sound absorption coefficient of the air?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't talking about sound absorption; it is taking about absorption of radiation (see first sentence of the introduction on page 1).  Here is a possible starting point: https://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/Demos/Absorption/Absorption.html (apart from the graph, it cites a couple of papers at the bottom).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. BTW does "apart from" here mean "besides"?

Comment: @zghqh, yes it does mean "besides".  Hopefully both the graph and the cited documents are useful.